# how do I store index of dataframe as new string?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, timestamp, save

So my dataframe is

```
timestamp = i.index.strftime("%b-%d %H")
print(timestamp)
Index(['Jan-25 17', 'Jan-25 17', 'Jan-25 17', 'Jan-25 17', 'Jan-25 17',
   'Jan-25 17', 'Jan-25 17', 'Jan-25 17', 'Jan-25 17', 'Jan-25 17',
   'Jan-25 17', 'Jan....7', 'Jan-25 17', 'Jan-25 17',
   'Jan-25 17', 'Jan-25 17', 'Jan-25 17', 'Jan-25 17', 'Jan-25 17'],
  dtype='object')
```

I want to store this value into a new string where timestamp='Jan-25 17'. How do I do that?
Actually I'm trying to `plt.savefig(timestamp+.'png')` and its showing ValueError: fname must be a PathLike or file handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, `timestamp` is the same string repeated a few times. If so:

```
ts = list(timestamp)[0]
```

You could then do:

```
plt.savefig(ts + '.png')
```